# Texture slots and viewing combined textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, texture-painting

I am painting textures in Cycles. My material contains multiple textures that are color mixed together in various fashions. I can use the Paint Slots in texture paint mode to view any given texture and paint on it. However, I want some way to view the whole combined stack of textures.

Is there a proper way to do this other than rendering or viewport rendering?

Answer (score 1):

Simply using Material Draw Mode for combined textures is the only option in Cycles for now. Blender Render used GLSL viewport to get combined, but the nice thing about Cycles Material Draw mode is that you can toggle shadeless in the N panel without affecting the shaders themselves. Also, you might be interested in looking at BPainter addon as it simplifies and streamlines the painting experience in Blender all around.